# Clearing state store of application

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to clear the state store of particular instance inside a kafka stream application, For example suppose if I'm maintaining list top 5 maximum values in a state, I want to clear it on hourly basis. Is there any way to do that - Without stopping the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems possible.

For example, you can register a `Punctuation` schedule that triggers once an our based on wall-clock time, that deletes all entries from the store.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#defining-a-stream-processor

Comment: Ya.. That should solve my problem.. I'll try to implement this and get back to you... Thanks

Comment: I'm using Aggregate function with state store.. Is there any way to clear the state store of Aggregate function?..

Comment: For DSL it's a little more tricky but not impossible. You need to add a custom `Processor` via `process()` and attach the internally used store of the `aggregation()` to this custom processor so it can access it. Than you can register a punctuation on your custom `Processor`. You can get all required information via `Topology#describe()`. It's kinda hack I have to admit.....

Comment: Ok.. I'll try to implement it.. Shouldn't we consider clearing state store in Stream processing as one of feature in upcoming release? Just a thought..

Comment: Some people issue a request for a TTL -- but both TTL and clearing a store is questionable at DSL level. And for Processor API one can implement it. Thus, no concrete roadmap to add this atm.